# Using SOQL aggregate functions

Tags: apex, soql

I have a table in salesforce that stores the topic selected by a person and  a person may select the same topic multiple times. At a high level this how the data is stored.

```
{"Person1, "Topic1", "Person1", "Topic1", "Person1", "Topic2", "Person2", "Topic3", "Person2", "Topic1", "Person2", "Topic3"}
```

I want to write a SOQL query that returns the person and the most frequently selected topic. For the above example the results will be like this:

```
 {"Person1", "Topic1", "Person2", "Topic3"}
```

I tried to use aggregate queries using **MAX** and **Count** but was not successful. Can any one tell me if its even possible with SOQL. Write now the only work around I am using is to dump this data in a map and looping through it to generate the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can write SOQL like this:

```
Select Person , Topic, count(Topic) CNT from TABLE group by Person , Topic order by  Person , Topic,  CNT DESC
```

This will return all topic counts selected by each person order by  CNT

Then you can apply logic to fetch top row (which has max count) for each person , for each topic.